# rails add restrictions to association based on enum value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `Media` model which has an enum

```
enum asset_type: { broadcast: 1, video: 2, audio: 3 }
```

and another model called `Post` and has an association with `media`

```
has_many :medias, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :medias
```

I want to add restrictions that per `Post` that would one `media` for asset type `audio` but I still want mutliple `broadcast` and `video`.

how can I achieve that?

Comment: _This is untested_ `has_one :audio_media, -> {where(asset_type: 'broadcast')}, class_name: 'Media'` Adding a unique index to the db would be an extra step also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if defining a `has_one` relationship really makes sense given the enum.

If you just need to enforce this on record creation or updates, consider handling it with callbacks.

An example on `Post`:

```rb
class Post
  has_many :medias, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :medias
  
  before_save :ensure_only_one_audio_media

  ...

  private

  def ensure_only_one_audio_media
    errors.add(:medias, 'already has an audio media attached') if medias.where(asset_type: 3).size > 1
  end
end
```

But depending on how you save medias to posts, you might need to validate this on `Media` instead.

If you're not locked into the current schema, and really want to do this with a relationship, one of the clearest ways would be to separate Audio to be its own Object.

```rb
class Post
  has_many :medias, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :audio
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :medias, :audio
```

I think this could be a good example of "designing your UX to meet your requirements". Instead of creating some safety catch at the model and dB level, just ensure your users don't have the opportunity to add more audio media to a post that already has one. In essence, I'm suggesting you can do this at the controller and view level without changing any of your existing code.

Comment: The model and DB are supposed to be "safety catches", they are supposed to enforce data integrity. Handling this in the UI is great but not a complete solution.